# About Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: videoSample' error

Tags: c#, opencv

I try to capture the cam frame, but it occurs the error when running few minutes.

C#

```
    private void CameraProcessFrame()
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            pictureBox2.Image = frame.ToBitmap();
            pictureBox2.Image.Save("C:\\Users\\YK Chen\\Desktop\\NEW\\" + frame.ToBitmap() + iCount.ToString() + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Have you succeeded to solve this problem? I have the same problem.